# Using listview as file/ folders explorer

Tags: vb.net, file, listview, directory, imagelist

I'm new to using listview to display icons. I have a few questions remaining...

I am currently using the following code as example. This code works fine, I have questions though

1. How do I get rid of the path name and only keep the file / folder name?
2. How do I also list folders alongside my files?
3. How can I click open these icons?

-

```
For Each File In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\")
    Dim icons As Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(File)
    ListView1.Items.Add(File.ToString, ImageList1.Images.Count - 1)
    ImageList1.Images.Add(icons)
    ListView1.Items.Add(File.ToString, ImageList1.Images.Count)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look into using treeview... hope that helps

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 0 To My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives.Count - 1
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives(x).IsReady = True Then
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives(x).Name, My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives(x).Name)
            TreeView1.Nodes(My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives(x).Name).Tag = My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives(x).Name
            For Each SubDirectory As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives(x).Name)
                TreeView1.Nodes(x).Nodes.Add(SubDirectory, Mid(SubDirectory, 4))
                TreeView1.Nodes(x).Nodes(SubDirectory).Tag = SubDirectory
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want more than just `File` and `Folder` name in the LV (like Explorer), I'd use `DirectoryInfo`:

```
Dim lvi As ListViewItem
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Temp")
Dim myIcon As Icon

' ext/icon lookup
Dim exts As New List(Of String)
ImageList1.Images.Clear()

For Each fi As FileInfo In di.EnumerateFiles("*.*")

    lvi = New ListViewItem
    lvi.Text = fi.Name
    lvi.SubItems.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(fi.FullName))

    lvi.SubItems.Add(((fi.Length / 1024)).ToString("0.00"))
    lvi.SubItems.Add(fi.CreationTime.ToShortDateString)

    If exts.Contains(fi.Extension) = False Then
        myIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fi.FullName)
        ImageList1.Images.Add(fi.Extension, myIcon)
        exts.Add(fi.Extension)
    End If

    lvi.ImageKey = fi.Extension
    myLV.Items.Add(lvi)
Next
```

The code uses a `List(of String)` to keep track of which icons have been added so that you do not add the same image over and over for repeated file types.  other wise, it displays the Name, Folder, Size, Date and icon.

[image]

The code using `Directory` would rely on `System.io.Path` more and Size and Date would not be available:

```
For Each s As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\Temp")

    lvi = New ListViewItem
    lvi.Text = Path.GetFileName(s)
    lvi.SubItems.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(s))

    Dim fileExt = Path.GetExtension(s)
    If exts.Contains(fileExt) = False Then
        myIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(s)
        ImageList1.Images.Add(fileExt, myIcon)
        exts.Add(fileExt)
    End If

    lvi.ImageKey = fileExt
    myLV.Items.Add(lvi)
Next
```

`How can I click open these icons` that is a different question.  Keep in mind that the LV just contains strings (text) and you removed the path from the file.  So you will have to glue them back together first to get the legal name (or store it in the LV).  That said, the LV has click and double click events like most other controls.